# Obtener URL de otra pestaña abierta

Tags: javascript, url

¿es posible obtener la URL del resto de pestañas abiertas?
Necesito poder detectar cuando el usuario de mi aplicación web la ha abierto más de una vez en el mismo navegador para no permitírselo. Gracias!

Comment: Pero cual es el motivo para no permitirse, si quieres que no muestre resultados o datos lo puedes hacer de otra forma

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas intentando no es posible, a parte de que no seria seguro para el cliente que puedas obtener las pestañas que tiene abiertas en su navegador.

Con extensiones si que puedes llegar a controlar las tabs, pero estas obligando al cliente instalar una extensión en su navegador.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda!

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo un [enlace](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) donde podrás ver el uso de las Chrome tabs para obtener lo que buscas.

La query que debes usar en JS es la siguiente (previamente debes activar la opción de tabs en chrome en el manifest. Al principio del enlace viene explicado cómo hacerlo.):

```
chrome.tabs.query(object queryInfo, function callback)
```

Donde el apartado `queryInfo` tiene los siguientes parámetros, a su vez (veremos las más importantes).

1. active: Buscará todas las pestañas activas.
2. groupId: Buscará las que tengan dicho groupId.

En cuanto a la función de callback, se recomienda recorrer los tabs, la hora de manejarlos depende del desarrollador.

```
function (arrayTabs) { (for tab in arrayTabs) { ... };
```

Comment: Tenía copiado lo anterior como comentario, en vez de respuesta pero parece ser que se puso como respuesta por error. Ya he editado la respuesta. Gracias @CandidMoe !

Comment: Esto no es posible, esta API solo sirve para cuando estas desarrollando una extensión para Chrome